# How to convert from Azure Append Blob to Azure Block Blob

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is their any  any to convert from Append Blob to Block Blob .

Regards
C

Comment: Use the Az Copy command on azure CLI -
azcopy copy 'https://<storage-account-name>.<blob or dfs>.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<append-or-page-blob-name>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.<blob or dfs>.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<name-of-new-block-blob>' --blob-type BlockBlob --block-blob-tier <destination-tier>

Answer (score 2):

For a blob conversion, I am using a

```
--blob-type=BlockBlob
```

option at the end of my azcopy.exe statement. So far it works well.

Good luck!

Comment: you can also duplicate a blob item using azcopy with the same source and destination but changed the output fille name or folder name

Answer (score 1):

> **Is their any any to convert from Append Blob to Block Blob .**

Once the blob has been created, its type cannot be changed, and it can be updated only by using operations appropriate for that blob type, i.e., writing a block or list of blocks to a block blob, appending blocks to a append blob, and writing pages to a page blob.

More information please refer to this link: [Understanding Block Blobs, Append Blobs, and Page Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs)

Answer (score 0):

> Is their any any to convert from Append Blob to Block Blob .

Automatic conversion between blob types is not allowed. What you would need to do is download the blob and reupload it as Block Blob.

Comment: Can we move the blob to a different location and then change type to block blob?

Comment: If by moving blob you mean copying blob to another container or storage account, then the answer is no. It won't work. You would need to download and reupload it as a different blob type.

Answer (score 0):

Given: i have source blob which is append blob 
And: i have to copy source to new blob container as block blob

When: i use CopyBlobToBlobckBlobContainer function
Then: destination container will have same blob as source but as block blob.

```
    public void CopyBlobToBlobckBlobContainer(string sourceBlobName)
    {
        var sourceContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(sourceConnectionString, BlobContainerName);
        var destinationContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(destinationConnectionString, OutBlobContainerName);
        destinationContainerClient.CreateIfNotExists();
        
        var sourceBlobClient = sourceContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(sourceBlobName);
        var sourceUri = sourceBlobClient.GenerateSasUri(BlobSasPermissions.Read, ExpiryOffset);

        var destBlobClient = destinationContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(sourceBlobName);
        var result = destBlobClient.SyncUploadFromUri(sourceUri, overwrite: true);
        var response = result.GetRawResponse();
        if (response.Status != 201) throw new BlobCopyException(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command on azure cli.

```
azcopy copy 'https://<storage-account-name>.<blob or dfs>.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<append-or-page-blob-name>' 'https://<storage-account-name>.<blob or dfs>.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<name-of-new-block-blob>' --blob-type BlockBlob --block-blob-tier <destination-tier>
```

> The --block-blob-tier parameter is optional. If you omit that
> parameter, then the destination blob infers its tier from the default
> account access tier setting. To change the tier after you've created a
> block blob, see Change a blob's tier.